# Cannot calculate number of verticies a model has. (Size of indeterminate array)

Tags: c++

I believe my issue is because I am comparing the size of a pointer to the size of a float, instead of comparing the number of elements in the array against a float.

```cpp
Model::Model(float* p_pos)
{
    // Determine vertex count
    m_vertexCount = (sizeof(p_pos) / sizeof(float)) / 3;
```

If I pass not as `float* p_pos`, but instead `float p_pos[]` nothing changes. How do I determine the number of verts in a model?

Comment: You cannot *really* pass `float p_pos[]` in C++ apart from few edges with known size at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C arrays decay to pointers when passed as a function argument, so you cannot extract the length. If you want to know the length when passed to the function, you have 3 choices:

- Switch to `std::array`
- Pass the length of the array along with the array
- Switch to `std::vector`

Comment: For completeness, there is also the option of using a reserved value or pattern to indicate the last element in the array (which is for example how nul-terminated `char` arrays work as strings).

Comment: This has worked, but now the triangle isn't rendering properly, one of the points is in the center of the viewport, instead of being 3/4 the way up. Does using a std::vector open up the possibility of my data not being in the correct order?